# Is there a free music database that I can download? I want to implement an music info site

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

I'm trying to implement a music info site, and I want to know if there's a free music database that I can use for this project.

Comment: You can try http://musicbrainz.org/

Comment: Database of what? All known songs and artists? Some sort of ID that allows you to identify an audio CD?

Answer (score 6):

Yes - Musicbrainz offers [database downloads](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Database_Download).

Answer (score 3):

dont know about download, but there are databases you can connect to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases